# problem with comparing two string/chars in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

So i have created a java server and a c++ client.
The java server sends a message with a printwriter to the c++ client to execute a command (the data transfer is correct, no problems with that)
Im using a strcmp() to check if the string that client recieved with recv() is the string i want but when i try to check it, it doesn't work. I've tried to print out the line with the recieved buffer and i dont see any problems.

Here is the code that recieves and checks the buffer(c++, ignore some values becouse this is a small piece of the code)

```
    char buffer[1024];

    if (recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Error CR#001" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (strcmp(buffer, "||clear") == 0) {
        system("cls");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: *it doesn't work* -- You need to specify exactly what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: `char buffer[1024];` isnt a c++ string. It's a character array. Are you sure that is c++ code?

Comment: If this is C++ use `std::string`. This is just fancy C code.

Comment: What is your proof that whatever is received in buffer will always be terminated with the `\0` null byte that C library functions, like `strcmp`, require? What is your proof that every call to `recv` will receive the complete message from the socket, and it will not be a partial message, that you must try again, to receive the rest of it? The shown code lacks many of required checks and logic that network clients must correctly implement.

Comment: This could consume a linefeed or carriage-return + linefeed depending on your protocol. Double check your specification.

Comment: _@Paabl0_ Do you want an answer with c++ code or for c?

Comment: c++ but im trying right now to figure it up alone rn, I appreciate for the help everybody.

Comment: One of the things Sam is hinting at is `if (recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)` is mostly useless. It catches errors, but discards the amount of data read from the socket if the call didn't fail, and that is utterly vital information in order to be sure you got all the data you needed (and no more).

Comment: @Paabl0 *but im trying right now to figure it up alone rn* -- C++ isn't the language to try and figure this out alone, and especially when it comes to socket programming.  There are just too many basic things wrong with your program that no book or tutorial on C++ sockets would have done.

Comment: Tip: If you're ever wondering what's actually in that buffer and why `strcmp` might not produce the result you expect just drop this into a debugger and *look at the memory `buffer` contains directly*. That usually eliminates all mysteries.

Comment: @Paabl0 Well, see my answer. It would have been nice, if you had been clear about that from start. Also I have to agree that _doesn't work_ is a very vague problem description at best.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i don't understand fully your code (i've too low c++ skills) so i'll search through the internet to explain for myself the things i dont understand. Appreciate for the help guys!

Comment: @Paabl0 Before you're going to start a long and unproductive journey, the information you need is just at hand here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to check it out soon.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you can use `std::string` for the `buffer`:

```
const ssize_t MAX_BYTES = 1024;
ssize_t noreceivedbytes;
std::string buffer;

buffer.reserve(MAX_BYTES + 1);
noreceivedbytes = recv(s, buffer.data(), MAX_BYTES, 0)
if (noreceivedbytes <= 0) {
    cout << "Error CR#001" << endl;
    return -1;
}
buffer.data()[noreceivedbytes] = '\0';

if (buffer == "||clear") {
    system("cls");
    return 1;
}
```

---

Safer c solution for completeness:

```
#define MAX_BYTES = 1024;
ssize_t noreceivedbytes;
chat buffer[MAX_BYTES];

noreceivedbytes = recv(s, buffer, MAX_BYTES - 1, 0)
if (noreceivedbytes <= 0) {
    cout << "Error CR#001" << endl;
    return -1;
}
buffer[noreceivedbytes] = '\0';

if (strcmp(buffer, "||clear") == 0) {
    system("cls");
    return 1;
}
```

---

**Please note:**

This answer brings you only over the top of the iceberg. There are many more things that could go wrong when dealing with sockets (as mentioned by others in comments).

`recv()` doesn't guarantee that the whole chunk of data sent from the server will be read completely. You could easily end up with partial strings like `"||cle"` or `"||c"`.

The least thing you'll need to do is to receive the bytes from the socket in a loop, until you have something at hand you can reasonably parse and match.

The simplest way to do so is to define a very primitive protocol, which preceeds payload data sent with it's size (take care of endianess problems when converting the size sent as integer value from the received data).
Having that at hand, you'll know exactly how many bytes you have to read until you have the payload chunk completed, such it can be parsed and compared reasonably.

How to do all that in detail exactly would lead to far to be answered here. There are whole books written about the topic (I'd recommend [Stevens, "Unix network programming"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139498761)).

Comment: Safer, but still leaves you up the proverbial creek if `recv` provided "||cle" or "||clearand more tokens that were sent later...".

Comment: @user4581301 That's true for both solutions unfortunately, but a full safe solution would lead too far here. It was merely to demonstate what to do as full c++ code interacting with the socket c-API, and at least to make sure that the data is forming a valid c-style string.

Comment: That's true for just about everything TCP. With TCP there is no escape from doing it the hard way.

Comment: @user4581301 see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783736/problem-with-comparing-two-string-chars-in-c/63783954?noredirect=1#comment112791102_63783954)

Comment: @user4581301 No, just how to do error prone and flawed code in valid c++ ;-)

Comment: @user4581301 Seriously. Mentioning all that (including the definition of a proper protocol et al.) would lead too far beyond the OP's question. Feel free to mention that in another answer, or maybe we should close the question as _needs details_ completely (I'm pretty sure there's even a dupe for it).

Comment: Only reason I brought it up was the asker's going to trip over it next. These are hard to answer, because you can see all of the questions coming, but to get it all down on paper, you've written half of Beej. Is there a duplicate, almost certainly. You or I might even have written it, though it'll probably be Remy.

Comment: @user4581301 _sigh_ You beat me to it. Done my duty.